# Matching the values of one dictionary to the keys of another dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

Evening All,

Hope you are well.

**My Objective**
I am trying to match the values of one dictionary to the keys of another.

`dict1` has keys but no values
`dict2` has keys and values

`dict2` has values that can be found as keys in `dict1`. I'm attempting to write code that identifies which values in `dict2` match the keys in dict1.

**My Attempt**
Commented code is below.

```
dict1 = {('dict1_key1',): [], ('dict1_key2',): []} #dictionary with keys, but no values;


for i in dict2.keys():  #iterate through the keys of dict2
    for x in dict2[i]:  #reaching every element in tuples in dict2
        if x == dict1.keys():  #if match found in the name of keys in dict1
            print(f"{i} holding {x}.") #print which key and value pair in dict 2 match the keys in dict1
```

The code works if I write the `for loop` as follows:

```
for i in dict2.keys():  #iterate through the keys of dict2
    for x in dict2[i]:  #reaching every element in tuples in dict2
        if x == dict1_key1 or x == dict1_key2():  #if match found in the name of keys in dict1
            print(f"{i} holding {x}.") #print which key and value pair in dict 2 match the keys in dict1
```

However, `dict1` in reality needs to be able to contain an varying number of keys which is why I had hoped that `if x == dict1.keys():` would work.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

@Mark Meyer

Examples values as requested:

```
dict1 = {('Tower_001',): [], ('Tower_002'): []}

dict2 = {1: 'Block_A', 'Tower_001'] #first key in dict2
        #skipping keys 2 through 13
        {14: ['Block_N', 'Tower_002']#last key in dict2
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a full example which would include `dict2`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer. Thanks, the example has been provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sets of all the value in the `dict1.keys` and `dict2.value`. Then just take the intersection of those sets to find keys that are also values:

```
dict1 = {('Tower_001',): [], ('Tower_005',): [], ('Tower_002',): []}

dict2 = {1: ['Block_A', 'Tower_001'], #first key in dict2
        14: ['Block_N', 'Tower_002']} #last key in dict2
         
         
set(k for l in dict2.values() for k in l) & set(k for l in dict1.keys() for k in l)
# {'Tower_001', 'Tower_002'}
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback and patience @MarkMeyer and pavel. I am new to programming, Stackoverflow is the only time I get to talk about programming, so apologies for the lack of clarification.

Looks like I'll need to read up on sets then.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Zen of Python @pavel (your comment is now gone), will give it a read. I'm busy with The Pragmatic Programmer.

Comment: @XpLoDe-NeF sets are great. They are much faster than nested loops for this kind of thing.